# Best method to handle dynamic View logic for showing controls, JQuery or return to controller for View refresh?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a situation in my View where certain controls ie Checkbox or Textbox should only show if a certain value is selected in a dropdown list. The question is what is the recommended approach to handle this:

1. Use JQuery to show a control when the dropdown is populated.
2. Return to controller, for relevant action to at least redisplay the View, passing through the View Model with new data, thereby enabling Razor to display the conditional controls. The advantages with this approach that I can see is that the process is managed by controller and same language(Razor/C#) is used.

Many thanks.

Comment: Why have I got a -1(-2 on reputation) on this question, and who has voted me down? I asked it in all seriousness, and I am sure there is a straight forward recommended "best practice" answer to it. Sorry I am puzzled.

Comment: you'll definitely want to use jquery. The controller has no business making this display change

Comment: Your question was (-1)'d because you did not read the FAQ. It clearly states "self sustained, non-discussion, non-polling" answers. Eonasdan's suggestion above says "use jQuery", and that's his/her opinion; mine could be "have a whole new page with the appropriate controls." And how would you decide which one is *correct*, while **at the same time** proving useful to other users? Votes are not about how serious you are, but about how good the question is, and how much you not deviate from the FAQ.

Comment: jquery is the correct answer from his question. He's not talking about .net webforms he's talking about mvc. Using the controller to make view changes based on a select box change doesn't follow separation of functions. Might as well use WebForms if you're going to postback for such a simple thing

Comment: Eonasdan, I really appreciate your advice here and wisdom. Yes I am talking about MVC, and yes seperation of concerns needs respecting. So thank you.

Comment: @SamJolly glad to help. I've add my comment as an answer, should you choice to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery or javascript is the best method here.

Using the controller to make view changes based on a select box change doesn't follow [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) or the [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).

You might as well use WebForms if you're going to make a  postback for such a simple thing